# CSS - Attempting to animate hue-rotate has no effect

Tags: css

I'm trying to do some animation with CSS. However, I can't seem to get hue-rotate to actually... well, animate. If I directly specify a filter in #docs-branding-logo, that gets applied, but when its in an animation, nothing happens

I'm currently on Firefox. I've tried this on Chrome and Edge as well, same result

```
@keyframes rainbowlogo {
0% {filter: hue-rotate(0deg)!important}  
10% {filter: hue-rotate(36deg)!important}
20% {filter: hue-rotate(72deg)!important}
30% {filter: hue-rotate(108deg)!important}
40% {filter: hue-rotate(144deg)!important}
50% {filter: hue-rotate(180deg)!important}
60% {filter: hue-rotate(216deg)!important}
70% {filter: hue-rotate(252deg)!important}
80% {filter: hue-rotate(288deg)!important}
90% {filter: hue-rotate(384deg)!important}
100% {filter: hue-rotate(360deg)!important}}

#docs-branding-logo {
animation-name:rainbowlogo!important;
animation-duration:3s!important;
animation-iteration-count:infinite!important;}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion (not related to your problem) - you can condense your keyframes down to a single line: `to { filter: hue-rotate(360deg); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `!important` will solve the problem

```css
@keyframes rainbowlogo {
0% {filter: hue-rotate(0deg)}  
10% {filter: hue-rotate(36deg)}
20% {filter: hue-rotate(72deg)}
30% {filter: hue-rotate(180deg)}
40% {filter: hue-rotate(144deg)}
50% {filter: hue-rotate(180deg)}
60% {filter: hue-rotate(216deg)}
70% {filter: hue-rotate(252deg)}
80% {filter: hue-rotate(288deg)}
90% {filter: hue-rotate(384deg)}
100% {filter: hue-rotate(360deg)}}

#docs-branding-logo {
animation-name:rainbowlogo;
animation-duration:3s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id='docs-branding-logo'> </div>
```

Comment: Ahhhh, okay. That makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: @PsychonNight the real reason is that important is ignored inside keyframes so it's not really about the rule being important here. All the rules are ignored so it's like the keyframes is empty

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thanks for the great points. Don't know that before!